The change of maximal eigenvalue when diagonal matrix times a positive semi-definite matrix
Now I have a positive semi-definite matrix $A$，identity matrix $I$，a diagonal matrix $D$，$D$ satisfied that it's diagonal elements are all positive.
The problem I considered is about the change of maximal eigenvalue between $A$, $A+DA$ and $A-DA$，I try some examples，and find the maximal eigenvalue of $A+DA$ is bigger than $A$，the maximal eigenvalue of $A-DA$ is smaller than $A$，so I wonder if this proposition can be proven in general
.
When diagonal elements of $D$ are all same，the proposition is easy to proven，but other situations are difficult to me.
Thank you for sharing your thoughts.

It is probably easiest to think of this modified matrix as $A(I + D)$, so that it's a question of the effect of multiplying $A$ by a diagonal matrix. It is notably that this $A(I + D)$ is similar to $(I + D)^{1/2}A(I + D)^{1/2}$, which is a positive semidefinite matrix

You can indeed prove that the largest eigenvalue of $A + DA$ is at least as large as that of $A$, but you can't make any guarantees about the extent without more information

@BenGrossmann Thank you for your comment.You mean I cannot extend to $A-DA$? If there are any counterexamples?

No I don’t, I just neglected to remark on that situation. I suspect that your guess is correct, but my previous argument is no longer quite correct.

A simple argument for both cases is that $A \pm A^{1/2}DA^{1/2}$ has the same non-zero eigenvalues as $A \pm DA$. From there, it suffices to note that adding one positive semidefinite matrix to another increases eigenvalues and subtracting one from the other decreases eigenvalues.

@BenGrossmann Thank you，But why they have same non-zero eigenvalues? Because A is positive semi-definite，if A isn't full rank，I think it's not obviously.

For matrices $P,Q$ such that $PQ$ is square, is generally true that $PQ$ and $QP$ have the same non-zero eigenvalues, regardless of whether $P$ and $Q$ are invertible (or for that matter, whether $P$ and $Q$ are square). It follows that the two matrices
$$
(A^{1/2} + DA^{1/2})A^{1/2}, \quad
A^{1/2}(A^{1/2} + DA^{1/2})
$$
have the same non-zero eigenvalues.
